# jqcloud and bootstrap conflict

Tags: jquery

I am using Bootstrap with jqcloud and find the jqcloud stops working when the Bootstrap is added. The issue is related to versions in jquery. I am asking for help with this statement which fails:

```
$("#headerwordcloud").jQCloud' is not a function
$("#headerwordcloud").jQCloud(hword_list);
```

For the JQCLOUD

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/wordcloud.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/jqcloud.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jqcloud-1.0.4.js"></script>
```

NEW CODE FOR BOOTSTRAP

```
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/bootply_ico.jpg">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/bootstrap/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/bootstrap/img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/bootstrap/img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/jquery.layout.js"></script>

    <link href="/plugins/jquery.layout.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootply.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootply/themes/metroid/theme.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are loading your scripts at the moment you are overwriting the methods that `jQCloud` will add to the `jQuery` / `$` object(s) when you load jQuery a second time. Load jQuery and jQuery UI first, then add your plugins depending on them:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/wordcloud.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jqcloud-1.0.4.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/plugins/jquery.layout.js"></script>
```

Note that I omitted the stylesheets in the example.

In the (unlikely) case that jQCloud requires an older version of jQuery you can use **[an approach like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)**

Comment: I solved it finally by moving the jquery include near to the end of the list